# How to over lap an image with text

Tags: html, css, image, text, overlap

Still learning how css works with html and I'm currently trying to overlap an image with text. This what I have so far.

```
<style>
  .aboutus_oven{
    background:url('Images/oventemp.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:760px;
    margin-top: 208px;
    position: absolute;
        }
</style>




<div class="aboutus_oven">
    <div class="aboutus_title">
        <h1> About Us</h1>
    </div>
</div>



.aboutus_title{
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left: 65px;    
  position: relative;
  }
```

I don't know if it is because they are both under the same class? The specific margins that I indicated within each class- are they going against each other?
I included an image showing what I want to achieve.

[image: tempimg]

Comment: Just increase the margin-top on the title

Comment: Oh and by the way, it's better to use % over pixels

Comment: can you provide your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/efnvt8qp/

```
.aboutus_oven{
    background:url('Images/oventemp.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:760px;
    margin-top: 208px;
    position: relative;
 }
.aboutus_title h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 36px;
  top: -18px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your aboutus_title styles are not in the style tags. to control what is in front or back, try using z-index. example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    <head>

    <style>
    .textontop{
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 200px;
    font-size: 60px;
    }

    .imageonbottom{
    z-index: 1;
    }
    
    body{
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <img class="imageonbottom" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602102317048-2be01617f96c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">

    <p class="textontop">TEXT</p>
    </body> 
    
    </html>
```